# How to implement Amazon Pay Guest Checkout?

Tags: spring-boot, checkout, amazon-pay

I'm creating a spring boot project to implement amazon pay. I could implement the General flow(below my html) but couldn't find any code to implement the guess checkout flow.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>CheckOut</h1>

    <div id="AmazonPayButton"></div>
    <script src="https://static-na.payments-amazon.com/checkout.js" th:inline="javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" th:inline="javascript">
        var payload = /*[[${payload}]]*/ "here";
        var signature = /*[[${signature}]]*/ "here";
        console.log(payload);
        console.log(signature);

        const amazonPayButton = amazon.Pay.renderButton('#AmazonPayButton', {
          merchantId: 'xxxx',
          publicKeyId: 'SANDBOX-xxxx',
          ledgerCurrency: 'USD',
          checkoutLanguage: 'en_US',
          productType: 'PayAndShip',
          placement: 'Home',
          buttonColor: 'Gold',
          estimatedOrderAmount: { "amount": "109.99", "currencyCode": "USD"},
          createCheckoutSessionConfig: {
              payloadJSON: payload,
              signature: signature
          }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That looks good so far.  Can you elaborate a little more on what you have done to handle the return on the "checkoutReviewReturnUrl" that you have passed on in the payload. That is the point where you want to decide what to do with the shoppers' data.

Comment: @marcus.kreusch actually this is my general flow(buyers needs to sign in to checkout) code which is work fine. I want to know how to implement the guest checkout. Can you please give me a lead on that one. I couln;t find any code on web :/

Comment: I'll be happy to help you with this ☺️I am just not sure, what you mean by guest checkout (i.e. whats the difference in your opinion?). There is only this one checkout flow on the Amazon Pay side and you would decide in your checkoutReviewReturn endpoint, if you want to continue creating a full account in your application or treat it as a guest session. There is no dedicated guest flow for Amazon Pay because it would not make a difference on their side.

Comment: I'm also confused with their documentation and can't find any other resources as well. Guest checkout means the buyers who doesn't have a Amazon Pay account can make chekout without sign in. https://amazonpay-onboarding.com/en/flow/new_buyer_flow/

Comment: I see  That is indeed a little confusing. When they say "guest", they mean your application and not the Amazon account. There is absolutely no way for a customer to use Amazon Pay without creating an Amazon account first.